# Plain password and encrypted password doesn't match in Shiro

Tags: java, shiro

```
public void doRegister() throws SQLException{ 
    String password = "test";
    PasswordService dps = new DefaultPasswordService(); 
     String temp = dps.encryptPassword(password); 
     System.out.println("AAAA  "+dps.passwordsMatch(password, temp)); 

}
```

this outputs AAAA false

What is the problem?

Comment: Perhaps you have to decrypt it before you can check it. It is probably stored in encrypted format and when you compare these two they obviously don't match. That would be my guess.

Comment: According to documentation, idont have to
[link]http://shiro.apache.org/static/current/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/authc/credential/PasswordService.html#passwordsMatch(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)[/link]

Comment: What is the data type of 'password'?

Comment: @PopoFibo it is String. I edited the question to indicate that.

Comment: Works just fine for me, what version of shiro are you using?

Comment: @PopoFibo I am using 1.2.2

Comment: Odd, works absolutely fine here - the exact lines of code you have

Comment: @PopoFibo by the way, by "works just fine" do you mean it outputs "AAAA true"

Comment: Yes, prints AAAA true with any String value of the password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. My default locale is `TR_tr`. When i run the program without changing the default locale it outputs `false`.

But when i run the program as below (it sets the default locale to ENGLISH) it outputs `true`

```
public class App { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        PasswordService psd = new DefaultPasswordService(); 
        String password = "333"; 
        String enc = psd.encryptPassword(password); 
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH); 
        System.out.println(Locale.getDefault()); 
        System.out.print(psd.passwordsMatch(password, enc)); 

    } 
}
```