# Shiro Authentication failed

Tags: hibernate, authentication, jsf-2, shiro

I use shiro 1.2.3 in a JSF2+Hibernate project. No luck to get a user authenticated. Can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

shiro.ini

```
[main]
cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager

hashService = org.apache.shiro.crypto.hash.DefaultHashService
hashService.hashIterations = 100000
hashService.hashAlgorithmName = SHA-256
hashService.generatePublicSalt = true

passwordService = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService
passwordService.hashService = $hashService
passwordMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.PasswordMatcher
passwordMatcher.passwordService = $passwordService

customSecurityRealm = com.sapienzo.common.CustomSecurityRealm
customSecurityRealm.credentialsMatcher = $passwordMatcher
securityManager.realms = $customSecurityRealm
```

ShiroUtils class (helper class to create salted hash)

```
public class ShiroUtils {

private static int HASH_ITERATIONS = 100000;

public static String createSaltedHash(String plainTextPassword) {
    DefaultHashService hashService = new DefaultHashService();
    hashService.setHashIterations(HASH_ITERATIONS);
    hashService.setHashAlgorithmName(Sha256Hash.ALGORITHM_NAME);
    hashService.setGeneratePublicSalt(true);

    DefaultPasswordService passwordService = new DefaultPasswordService();
    passwordService.setHashService(hashService);
    String encryptedPassword = passwordService.encryptPassword(plainTextPassword);

    return encryptedPassword;
}
}
```

saving a user to database while registration (getting username and password from form fields)

```
...
user.setUsername(username);
user.setPassword(ShiroUtils.createSaltedHash(password);
userService.saveUser(user);
...
```

login (again username and password from form fields)

```
UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(user.getUsername(), ShiroUtils.createSaltedHash(user.getPassword()));
Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
currentUser.login(token);
```

CustomSecurityRealm.java

```
public class CustomSecurityRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {
    public CustomSecurityRealm() {
        setName("CustomSecurityRealm");
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken authenticationToken) throws AuthenticationException {
        UsernamePasswordToken token = (UsernamePasswordToken) authenticationToken;
        if (token.getUsername() == null) {
            return null;
        }
        UserService userService = new UserService();
        String saltedHashPassword = userService.getPasswordByUsername(token.getUsername()); //get encrypted password from DB

        if( saltedHashPassword != null ) {
            SimpleAuthenticationInfo authn = new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(token.getUsername(), saltedHashPassword, getName());
            return authn;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principalCollection) {
        return null;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging out the code line by line, i noticed that `passwordsMatch` method which is used for password comparison always returns *false* regardless of the inputs.

For example:

```
String plainTextPassword = "foo";
DefaultPasswordService passwordService = new DefaultPasswordService();
String encryptedPassword = passwordService.encryptPassword(plainTextPassword);
boolean result = passwordService.passwordsMatch(plainTextPassword, encryptedPassword);
System.out.println(result);
```

Output is *false*. Found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21354354/plain-password-and-encrypted-password-doesnt-match-in-shiro) later. Causing this is a reported bug. If your default locale is different than **English** shiro gets confused when (un)capitalizing letters. You should set your default locale to `Locale.ENGLISH` to fix this.